# At what point does a PhD student have to commit to a research group (US)?

Tags: phd, united-states

I am planning to apply to PhD programs in the US this Fall (to start in 2020). I have been looking at various institutions and research groups in my area and I am wondering at what point a PhD student generally has to commit themself to a particular research lab/group?

For example, is it at the time they apply for the program at that institution? I can imagine this might be the case, because the labs will have a limited amount of funding, so the institution would need to know what group you will be working with when they make offers, to ensure that no group ends up being over-subscribed for their funding level. Would an offer for a PhD studentship typically be conditional that you join a particular lab after accepting?

However, I have read in some places that, during the first year or semester, PhD students typically 'shop around' the various labs they are interested in, to speak to more people in the lab than they were able to meet before they applied, before they decide which lab they will join. This seems to make better sense to me, in terms of finding the right 'fit' with a lab/PI. However, if the research group is not determined until after a PhD student starts the program, is there a possibility that some labs might end up over-subscribed; some students may not end up at the lab they wanted when they applied; or even that a PhD student could end up not being placed with a PI at all?

Or, does the system work differently for different institutions?

I have heard about some PhD students changing groups mid-way through their PhD, because they found the first lab was not a good fit. So, it seems that there must be some level of flexibility to move around and change groups after starting a program.

Comment: This varies far too much by discipline and institution to answer in a general way.  All of the possibilities that you've mentioned are actually possibilities.

Comment: @BrianBorchers ok, I appreciate your input. However, to me, 'it varies a lot by discipline and institution' is still a helpful answer. It seems that I need to find out more about how the programs at specific institutions I am applying to work.

Comment: You have to read the details of the program you are considering. There's no way around that. Yes, general tendencies exist (as explained in the answer) but ultimately there's no substitute for actually reading about the details of each program. Btw, Fluid Dynamics research could also be part of a physics PhD program.

Answer (score 1):

This can depend a bit on field and even by institution. It would also make some difference if you are applying with a BS or an MS already in hand. If you are early in the process then the early part of the doctoral program will likely involve advanced coursework, so choosing a specialty can typically be put off.

But starting later, ready for research, it will probably be an advantage to know, going in, which group (or groups) you are most compatible with.

But overall, your assessment in the question is correct. People choose a bit later than first contact and some people change. In math, for example, there is less reason to choose early than in, say nuclear physics, where expensive labs might be part of the process.

I changed groups because I changed institutions. The old situation didn't work out for me. I joined the new group relatively soon but held an MA at that point and knew who I wanted to work with. But it wasn't a choice made in the first weeks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this is helpful. The field is Engineering (Fluid Dynamics). Perhaps I should add that to my question? Also, I do already have a Masters (from a UK institution). Something else I was wondering is whether US PhD programs differ in length/structure, depending on whether you already have a Masters or not. But, perhaps that should be the subject of a different question?

Comment: The coursework in the US is to get you prepared for qualifiers. If you have the knowledge to do that, you can often (usually?) bypass the coursework. But many entering students need at least some of that. The most important "structure" is the requirement to pass the qualifying exams and write an acceptable dissertation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, typically in the US, candidates have to pass exams, before they are allowed to start doing actual research. So, during that period, it would be more feasible to explore different labs/PIs. Thanks again!

Comment: @Time4Tea "typically in the US, candidates have to pass exams, before they are allowed to start doing actual research" - this is not typically true (maybe never true) in biological sciences in the US at least, nor is it true for the engineers I've worked with (mostly biomedical and CS). There is still a preliminary exam of some sort, but research starts in parallel to any prep for it. As with your main question, though, you really have to see how each individual program is structured.

Comment: @BryanKrause ok, thanks for your helpful advice. So, the purpose of the preliminary/qualifying exams is to make sure students are on the 'right track' and have the basic knowledge they need to pursue their projects?

Comment: Actually, not precisely correct. The exams assure that students have sufficient _breadth_ in the field. The research and dissertation is more about depth in a small part. True in Math at least, and many other fields.

Comment: @Time4Tea Yep, I'd agree with Buffy about breadth assurance. In addition, in the program I was in and several others I am familiar with, a major part of the prelims is a research proposal (though again typically a bit of research is necessary to even get to the stage of writing a proposal, collecting preliminary data, learning techniques, etc).

Comment: @BryanKrause ok, thanks again to you both.